# sbt different libraryDependencies in test than in normal mode

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, typesafe

Because of conflicting / transitive (elasticsearch / lucene / jackrabbit) dependencies i want to have different libraryDependencies in test than i have when normally running the app. I solved it with the setup below, but this requires running activator with -Dtest and this will prevent my app from running normally when i'm done testing. The other way around, i.e. running just activator, *will* run my app but will not run my test. So, not very convenient and i think this can be done much better (btw i'm very new to sbt/scala)

```
name := """example"""

version := "0.1"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

// fork in Test := true

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"

javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.file=conf/test-logger.xml"

// run activator -Dtest
if (sys.props.contains("test")) {
  Seq[Project.Setting[_]](  
    libraryDependencies ++= {
      Seq(
          javaJdbc,
          javaEbean,
          cache,
          javaWs,
          "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
          "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6",
          "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.5.0",
          "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.3",
          "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-core" % "3.6.0",
          "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.7.4" exclude("org.apache.lucene", "lucene-core"),
          "javax.jcr" % "jcr" % "2.0",
          "org.apache.jackrabbit" % "jackrabbit-core" % "2.11.2",
          "org.apache.jackrabbit" % "jackrabbit-jcr2dav" % "2.11.2",
          "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.11",
          "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.11",
          "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
          "com.typesafe.akka" %  "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.14" % "test"
        )
    }
  )
} else {
  Seq[Project.Setting[_]](
   libraryDependencies ++= {
      Seq(
          javaJdbc,
          javaEbean,
          cache,
          javaWs,
          "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
          "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6",
          "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.5.0",
          "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.3",
          "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.7.4",
          "javax.jcr" % "jcr" % "2.0",
          "org.apache.jackrabbit" % "jackrabbit-core" % "2.11.2",
          "org.apache.jackrabbit" % "jackrabbit-jcr2dav" % "2.11.2",
          "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.11",
          "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.11",
          "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
          "com.typesafe.akka" %  "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.14" % "test"     
       )
    }
  )
}


//.. our private nexus repo left out here

resolvers += "JBoss Repository" at "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories"

resolvers += "JBoss Third-Party Repository" at "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://deadbolt.ws/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a setup where I can really test whether this works, but from how I understand sbt dependencies it should:

Dependencies can have a kind of scope called a configuration. Typically, this is used to define test only dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %  "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.14" % "test"
```

But you should also be able to define compile time and run time only dependencies using "compile" and "runtime" instead.

sbt prints me a warning if I use dependencies with different versions. The problem is, that this will use a different version of a dependency to compile it and then to run it with tests. So it will be run against a different version than it was compiled with. There are of course libraries, where this will work, especially, if you run with a newer version that what you use to compile.

If you really need to compile your application twice with different dependencies and use one build for running and one for testing, I fear, there won't be a solution without extending sbt or something like that.

You could try to make two modules, one with the main code and one for testing and then try to cross-build two different versions of the first module. Sbt can easily cross-build over multiple Scala versions, but I don't think it can do it out of the box for multiple versions of a library.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @dth, you put me on the right track. The settings below worked for me:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      cache,
      javaWs,
      "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
      "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6",
      "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.5.0",
      "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.3",
      "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-core" % "3.6.0" % "compile,test",
      "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.7.4" % "compile,runtime",
      "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.7.4"  % "test" exclude("org.apache.lucene", "lucene-core"),          
      "javax.jcr" % "jcr" % "2.0",
      "org.apache.jackrabbit" % "jackrabbit-core" % "2.11.2",
      "org.apache.jackrabbit" % "jackrabbit-jcr2dav" % "2.11.2",
      "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.11",
      "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.11",
      "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %  "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.14" % "test"     
   )
}
```